# Failed to create NativeModule "UIManager" in React Native app

Tags: android, react-native

After upgrading to the latest version of React Native (0.70.3), my Android app builds fine but when I run it I get the below error. It references a class that seems to be in the react-native-video-with-ads npm package, which is not something that I use. I tried manually installing this package, but still get the same error. Any ideas?

```
2022-10-23 10:08:02.997 25180-25295/com.marriage365.app E/unknown:NativeModuleInitError: Failed to create NativeModule "UIManager"
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager: android.view.View com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager.createViewInstance(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext) failed to verify: android.view.View com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager.createViewInstance(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext): [0x4]  can't resolve returned type 'Reference: android.view.View' or 'Unresolved Reference: com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerView' (declaration of 'com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager' appears in /data/app/~~Nq33b85Ca7DH-MTNDVGU3Q==/com.marriage365.app-mNOnqtNxaI4Mm9muOh5Rig==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage.createViewManagers(ReactVideoPackage.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.getOrCreateViewManagers(ReactInstanceManager.java:928)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.createUIManager(ReanimatedPackage.java:75)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.getModule(ReanimatedPackage.java:31)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:159)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:147)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.create(ModuleHolder.java:191)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule(ModuleHolder.java:156)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule(NativeModuleRegistry.java:170)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:502)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:478)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:89)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:47)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1240)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1182)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1600(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1136)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2022-10-23 10:08:02.997 25180-25295/com.marriage365.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.marriage365.app, PID: 25180
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager: android.view.View com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager.createViewInstance(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext) failed to verify: android.view.View com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager.createViewInstance(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext): [0x4]  can't resolve returned type 'Reference: android.view.View' or 'Unresolved Reference: com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerView' (declaration of 'com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager' appears in /data/app/~~Nq33b85Ca7DH-MTNDVGU3Q==/com.marriage365.app-mNOnqtNxaI4Mm9muOh5Rig==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage.createViewManagers(ReactVideoPackage.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.getOrCreateViewManagers(ReactInstanceManager.java:928)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.createUIManager(ReanimatedPackage.java:75)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage.getModule(ReanimatedPackage.java:31)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:159)
        at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:147)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.create(ModuleHolder.java:191)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule(ModuleHolder.java:156)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule(NativeModuleRegistry.java:170)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:502)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:478)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:89)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:47)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1240)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1182)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1600(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1136)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still facing this issue:

Add this following code to buildscript in `android/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { 
            force 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.13.3'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.